# Getting "The service is invalid" when running cordova run ios

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm having trouble running a cordova app on an iphone 6 using  `cordova run ios`.

I'm getting this error

```
[ 49%] Copying /Users/matias/sunpower/energylink-components-library/apps/energylink-connect2/platforms/ios/build/device/EnergylinkConnect2.app/AppIcon76x76~ipad.png to device
[ 52%] CreatingStagingDirectory
[ 57%] ExtractingPackage
[ 60%] InspectingPackage
[ 60%] TakingInstallLock
[ 65%] PreflightingApplication
[ 65%] InstallingEmbeddedProfile
[ 70%] VerifyingApplication
[ 75%] CreatingContainer
[ 80%] InstallingApplication
[ 85%] PostflightingApplication
[ 90%] SandboxingApplication
[ 95%] GeneratingApplicationMap
[100%] Installed package /Users/matias/sunpower/energylink-components-library/apps/energylink-connect2/platforms/ios/build/device/EnergylinkConnect2.app
------ Debug phase ------
Starting debug of 17ad5aa2e5c26f2f36e3a8ac1532bf0c1e40048e (N71AP, iPhone 6s, iphoneos, arm64) a.k.a. 'iPhone de Matias' connected through USB...
[  0%] Looking up developer disk image
[ 90%] Mounting developer disk image
[ 95%] Developer disk image already mounted
2020-02-11 11:21:15.310 ios-deploy[51274:22344371] [ !! ] Error 0xe8000022: The service is invalid. AMDeviceSecureStartService(device, CFSTR("com.apple.debugserver"), NULL, &con)
ios-deploy: Command failed with exit code 253
```

- OS: MacOS Mojave
- Device: iPhone 6s
- iOS: 13.3.1
- xcode: 11.0 (11A420a)

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be working, after upgrading Xcode to its latest version (11.3.1) and building the app from xcode.

After that I could even run it from the command line